# How to pass ajax into a spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Am getting values in Ajax page

```
function GetInfoDivision()
{
     var data = $("#storeName").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",   
        url : "hello",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),    
        dataType : 'json',              
        //timeout : 100000, 
        success : function(map) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display(data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
```

But Controller page getting null value ...Ajax data value not passed to the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String employeeLogin(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
         String sname = request.getParameter("storeName");   
         System.out.println("s="+sname);    
            shopModel s = new shopModel();
              s.setStoreName(sname);

            //boolean result = employeeService.employeeLogin(employee);
              boolean result =false;
             if(result == true){

                    model.addAttribute("message", "Successfully logged in.");
             }
             else
             {
                model.addAttribute("message", "Username or password is wrong.");
            }
            return "redirect:index.jsp";
        }
```

[image: see]

Comment: have you tried not stringify-ing your data?

Comment: @Ivin Raj: your "data" is just a string value, you cannot just JSON.stringify it like that. To understand, you should open tab "Network" under Chrome F12 Developer Tool to see what was actually sent.

Comment: where is Restcontroller annotation added?

Comment: @HoàngLong see my updated image

Comment: @IvinRaj: your picture is showing the *Source* tab, not the *Network* tab.

Comment: Why down vote ..

Comment: Some people’s are following and down vote shameless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If storeName is just a string then you can use `@RequestParam`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String employeeLogin(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,
@RequestParam(value = "storeName", required = false) String storeName) {

String sname = storeName;
}
```

and in Ajax call you can have call like

```
url : "hello" + "?storeName=" + data
```

and remove below property in Ajax call

```
data : JSON.stringify(data),
```

Your Ajax will look like below:

```
function GetInfoDivision()
{
     var data = $("#storeName").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",   
        url : "hello" + "?storeName=" + data,
        dataType : 'json',              
        //timeout : 100000, 
        success : function(map) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display(data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
```

Comment: how to multiple values in Ajax data @Amit K Bist

Comment: it's working in single value is fine but i need to pass multiple values in Ajax data @Amit K Bist

Comment: It depends if you want to pass multiple values as `@RequestParam` or as `@RequestBody`?, if you want to pass as `@RequestParam` to the controller then you can do something like `"hello" + "?storeName=" + data + "&secondParam=" + secondParamValue` or you can pass data node in the ajax as `data: ({storeName : data, secondParam: secondParamValue})` and url should have only  url : "hello" in the ajax call.

Comment: Call will look like below: `var firstParamValue = $("#firstParam").val();
  var secondParamValue = $("#secondParam").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",   
        url : "hello",
  data: ({firstParamName : firstParamValue, secondParamName: secondParamValue}),
        dataType : 'json',              
        success : function(map) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        }
    });`

Comment: Controller will be like `public String employeeLogin(@RequestParam("firstParamName") String firstParamName,
   @RequestParam("secondParamName") String secondParamName, 
   ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request)`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `@RequestBody` annotation in the parameter of the controller function.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String employeeLogin(@RequestBody ModelMap model) {
```

Comment: Maybe removing the  `HttpServletRequest request` from the method parameters.  I edited the answer. If you need access to the Request object you can inject it in your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String methodname(@RequestParam("data") String data) {
    ...
    return "";
}
```